# 'cut' option not appearing in shortcut menu in Excel 2013

Tags: excel

In my Excel 2013, the 'cut' option has stopped appearing suddenly. I want to cut a few rows and paste it somewhere else, so I highlight three rows, but when I right click, the shortcut menu opens. But, I cannot see 'cut' option. I only see 'copy' followed by other options.

Comment: use the shortkey ctrl + x, or on mac cmd + x

Answer (score 0):

That looks like someone was running macros, without knowing what they do. Happened to me some time ago, it was a bit fun. This is how I recovered from there:

```
Control Panel > Uninstall > Office > Change > Repair
```

Looks a bit rough, but it is quite secure and you need about 10-20 minutes for it. The other option is to go to the registries and to delete from there, but its possible that you hack yourself quite a bit.

---

Another option is to [take a look here](https://superuser.com/questions/511580/delete-default-template-in-microsoft-excel-2010) and to delete the original template. It may help.